# Joomla virtuemart filter issue with JRoute

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

Please help me, i use Joomla + Virtuemart

I added search filter by customfields, but there was a problem with pagination and sort URL

I found a strange in code, this function:

echo JRoute::_('&customfields[5][0]=35')

generate url:

/index.php?**customfields[5]=Array**

should look like

/index.php?**customfields[5][0]=35**

I would be happy if you can help me find a part of code where I can find the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to the settings of sh404sef component.